# Node.js - Callback don't halt the execution when got hit

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I've been developing an application using node.js and in rare cases **Callback doesn't halt the execution when got it and the execution continues**

**Method 1**

```
utilityMethod(arg1, arg2, arg2,function(err,result){

      if(err){
         callback(err);
      }

       if(result){
          callback(null,result);
       }
        else{
           callback('an error');
        }
     });

     function utilityMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3, callback){

            //some logic
            if(err){
               return callback(err);
             }
            else{
              return callback(null,'success');
            }
     }
```

So I'm using the below code (Method 2)to halt the execution

**Method 2**

```
 utilityMethod(arg1, arg2, arg2,function(err,result){

      if(err){
         return callback(err);
      }

       if(result){
          return callback(null,result);
       }
        else{
           return callback('an error');
        }
     });
```

I'm not sure why the method 1 fails. Which one is the right way to use?
Also why the method 1 fails?

**Note: I'm using the above methods inside the async.each().
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with your Method 1 is that you do not have a **return** statement in your `if(err)` clause, so your callback method gets called two times.

What you should do here if you really want to halt the execution of your program is throw an exception

```
Model.find().exec(function(err,result) {
  if(err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  // .. do what you want with the result ..
});
```

Comment: Sry. Just updated the actual implementation. Thanks for your input. I've resolved using **return**, but wanted to make sure that I didn't go wrong anywhere

Comment: That was the only mistake there. But you should try using exceptions or promises, that would be cleaner :) !

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to exit the function and not the program?

Comment: Well throwing an exception does not necessarily halt the application if it's caught correctly!

Comment: Agreed **IF** it is caught correctly but that is the point of the node callback pattern. To bubble up errors as necessary rather than having to bury functions in a stack of `try/catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

To exit a function you need to use `return`. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> When a return statement is called in a function, the execution of this function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller. If the expression is omitted, undefined is returned instead.

So Model2 is the correct way although it could be cleaned up a bit:

```
Model.find().exec(function(err, result) {
  if (err) { return callback(err); } // will exit here if error

  // no need to explicitly return here as it's the termination of the function
  callback(null, result); // result could be null but callback can handle that
});
```

And unless you are doing something in this function you can push this logic into `callback` by simply using:

```
Model.find(callback);

function callback(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    // do something with err
  }

  // do soemthing with result
  // ....
}
```